# Selecting Comments by their inner xml in xpath/xsl

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, comments

Given the following xml document

```
<root>
   <childnode0/>
   <childnode2/>
   <!--Comment1-->
   <childnode3/>
   <childnode4/>
   <!--Comment2-->
</root>
```

I know the xpath to select all the comments at a particular level in xsl

```
string xPath = "/root/comment()";
```

However i'd like to select a comment where the inner xml is "Comment2".

Any ideas?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This

```
/root/comment()[.='Comment2']
```

seems to work.

Comment: perfect -> .= Thanks

Answer (score 1):

maybe this would work:
`/root/comment()[2]`

Comment: That would work in above example.. However i kept the example simple... It will be in a much larger XML document.. so that's why i needed to be able to select by inner XML..